# how to restrict edit area in VIM

Tags: vim

I have a very large file and want to edit only part of the file say line X to line Y. One way to do that is extract that part of file edit it and replace it in original. Instead is it possible in VIM to restrict all operations(like search) to line X to line Y and also restrict any write to area outside line X to line Y.

I know that `:X,Y s/m/r/g` will do the necessary search and replace between line X and Y.
But the requirement is to start the VIM in a mode where only line X, Y are accessible for edit and write.

Answer (score 2):

In this situation, Emacs' [Narrowing](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Narrowing.html) which focuses on some portion of the buffer fits the task.

There are some Vim plugins like [NrrwRgn](https://github.com/chrisbra/NrrwRgn) and [vim-narrow](https://github.com/PeterRincker/vim-narrow) which emulate Emcas' narrowing feature. You can search by `vim narrow`.

Typically, by using a Vim plugin, you can visually select an area and type the provided keymap to narrow it into a scratch buffer. You can save it back after editing.

---

In case you're interested, you can also try Emacs with a popular preset config like [Spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs) which emulates Vim editing styles.

When ready, you can visually select an area and press `C-x n n` to narrow down, edit the area, and then `C-x n w` to widen back to the entire buffer.

Answer (score 0):

vim doesn't provide any way to allow only certain parts of a file to be edited.